# Detect if certain named workbook is open. error 53

Tags: ms-access, vba

I used the code provided by Siddharth Rout in the following threat.
[Detect whether Excel workbook is already open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open)

My goal was to check if a certain named workbook was open and depending on the result perform certain actions.
This was the result.

```
Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String)

 Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long

On Error Resume Next
ff = FreeFile()
Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case ErrNo
Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select

End Function
```

The following piece refers back to the function and depending on the result performs certain actions.

```
Dim xls As Object
Dim Answer As String
Dim Mynote As String

If IsWorkBookOpen(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Report.xlsm") = 
True Then

Mynote = "The Report is still open. Do you want to save the Report ?"
Answer = MsgBox(Mynote, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Warning Report open")

If Answer = vbYes Then


MsgBox "Please Save your Report under a new name and close it. then press update again"
Exit Sub

Else
Set xls = GetObject(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Report.xlsm")
xls.Close True

End If
Else
End If
```

This used to work perfectly in the past but since today it suddenly gives me error 53.

While trying to resolve the issue I discovered the error only occurs when the named workbook is not on the desktop. Strangely enough it did not have this issue in the past. I specifically tested that because the file will not always be on the desktop.
I tried several backups tracking back 2 months and even those show the same error now.

While searching the internet for this issue i found this thread,
[Check if excel workbook is open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587762/check-if-excel-workbook-is-open)
where they suggest to change the following pieces,
(ErrNo = Err) in to (Errno = Err.Number)
(ff = FreeFile_()) in to (ff = FreeFile)
I did both together and independitly. eventhough i dont really see the relation between the error and Freefile.
This did not change the error at all.

While I am currious to why this error suddenly occurs I really do need a solution or alternative.

what i need it tot do again is,
- Check if named workbook is open.
- when it is open a Msgbox with yes and no option should appear.
- On "No" it should close the named workbook and continue with whatever is below of what i posted.
- On yes it should pop a message box and stop.

Any help that can be provided will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you not need to check if the file exists first? Error 53 means file not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the file exists before checking if it is open;

```
Function FileExists(ByVal strFile As String, Optional bFindFolders As Boolean) As Boolean
'Purpose:   Return True if the file exists, even if it is hidden.
'Arguments: strFile: File name to look for. Current directory searched if no path included.
'           bFindFolders. If strFile is a folder, FileExists() returns False unless this argument is True.
'Note:      Does not look inside subdirectories for the file.
'Author:    Allen Browne. http://allenbrowne.com June, 2006.
    Dim lngAttributes    As Long

    'Include read-only files, hidden files, system files.
    lngAttributes = (vbReadOnly Or vbHidden Or vbSystem)

    If bFindFolders Then
        lngAttributes = (lngAttributes Or vbDirectory)        'Include folders as well.
    Else
        'Strip any trailing slash, so Dir does not look inside the folder.
        Do While Right$(strFile, 1) = "\"
            strFile = Left$(strFile, Len(strFile) - 1)
        Loop
    End If

    'If Dir() returns something, the file exists.
    On Error Resume Next
    FileExists = (Len(Dir(strFile, lngAttributes)) > 0)

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Minty, Your answer makes so much sense I feel stupid for not thinking about it. Geus its Friday. thanks for the function that saves me some time as well. very much appreciated.

Comment: No problem, Friday-itis hits all of us. Can you mark as answered ?